# Buffer Overflow - Array Index Out of Bounds (Critical)

Tags: c++, klocwork

Here is my code.

this is the error I get.

```
Buffer Overflow - Array Index Out of Bounds (Critical)
 > - Code: ABV.MEMBER --> i_rgb_to_xyz()
 > - Message: Array '&(xyz.x)' of size 1 may use index value(s) 2.
```

```
// Go through all input rgb's and push result to output vector
    for (auto pt : rgb)
    {
        point_xyz xyz;
        matrix_mul3x1(M, &pt.r, &(xyz.x));     //this line is the error line
        output.push_back(xyz);
    }


void matrix_mul3x1(const double* A, const double* B, double* C)
{
    C[0] = A[0] * B[0] + A[1] * B[1] + A[2] * B[2];
    C[1] = A[3] * B[0] + A[4] * B[1] + A[5] * B[2];
    C[2] = A[6] * B[0] + A[7] * B[1] + A[8] * B[2];
}
```

this is the definition for rgb

```
const vector<point_rgb>& rgb
```

this is the defition for point_rgb

```
typedef struct
{
    double r;
    double g;
    double b;
} point_rgb;
```

this is the defition for point_xyz

```
typedef struct
{
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;
} point_xyz;
```

Can someone please suggest how to fix this issue? 
I don't really understand this clockwork error.

Comment: What is point_xyz?

Comment: And you cannot treat a struct like array

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @Thomas Sablik how this will help with klocworks errors?

Comment: I will be better able to provide help if you provide code that I can easily understand and use to reproduce the problem

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the `matrix_mul3x1`'s body:

```
void matrix_mul3x1(const point_xyz* A, const point_rgb* B, double* C)
{
    C[0] = A->x * B->r + A->y * B->g + A->z * B->b;
    // ....
}
```

You cannot access the members of a struct treating it like an array.

In your case you can use [tuple](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple) instead of struct too.

```
using data = std::tuple<double, double, double>;
void matrix_mul3x1(const data& A, const data& B, data& C)
{
    std::get<0>(C) = std::get<0>(A) * std::get<0>(B) ...;
    // ....
}
```